# Run a SQL Script without displaying result in result window

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a DB initialization script, which does several hundred inserts to the DB... every time I release, I need to run this script and I always get a notification, that I have too many result windows for this script. This is how the script looks like:

My SQL script contains a mix of select and insert statements like this:

```
-- I don't want these select statements to produce any result in the result window
SELECT @var1 := col1 FROM table1 WHERE col1 = 'some value';
SELECT @var2 := col2 FROM table2 WHERE col2 = 'some other value';

INSERT INTO table3(col1) VALUES(@var1);
INSERT INTO table4(col1) VALUES(@var2);
```

Is there any **SQL command** that I could include on top of this long script, which tells MySQL Workbench (V 6.3) that I am not interested in seeing the result for this particular script?

Comment: I am not aware of workbench but you can definitely use 'mysqldump' command and redirect the output to a log file.

Comment: How comes that your INSERT statements produce a result set? However, if you have select statements for which you are not interested to see the result set, try [the DO command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/do.html) instead.

Comment: @MikeLischke: thanks, I have some select statements like this in the script: `SELECT @var1 := col1 FROM table1 WHERE col2 = 'some value';`... Would I be able to use the `do` command to execute the above select? I need `@var1` value in the following `insert` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The Output is located at the bottom of MySQL Workbench. Its select box includes the Action Output, History Output, and Text Output options.

The Action Output panel displays a summary of the communication between the active MySQL connection in MySQL Workbench and the MySQL server, and can refer to errors or general information.

The History Output panel provides a history of SQL operations carried out in MySQL Workbench for the active MySQL connection. The time and SQL code for each operation is recorded.

Switch from "Action Output" to "History Output"

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-develop-sql-editor-history.html

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there a command that I could include in the script to disable the output..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment by @MikeLischke, I used [Do command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/do.html) to execute the select statements, without producing any result in the result window:

```
DO (SELECT @var1 := col1 FROM table1 WHERE col1 = 'some value');
DO (SELECT @var2 := col2 FROM table2 WHERE col2 = 'some other value');

INSERT INTO table3(col1) VALUES(@var1);
INSERT INTO table4(col1) VALUES(@var2);
```